# How to measure and quantify concentration or focus?

Tags: measurement, attention, psychophysics, experiment-design, concentration

How can we measure and quantify concentration or focus? For example, if I were to say:

> "If you do Activity X while using Y, you will be more concentrated
>   than if you were using Z"

How can I quantify that? And what tests should I do to actually prove that statement? Examples are appreciated.

<sub>**Background**
I am trying to build some different technology products and I want them to help the user stay more focused than they would using a competitor product of the same kind. The only research I've done so far was to build some interfaces and ask the user how they feel.</sub>

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/5013/11318

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**
Attention can be quantified with a sustained attention to response task.

**Background**
I think with focus or concentration you mean sustained **[attention](https://www.psytest.net/index.php?page=Daueraufmerksamkeit&hl=en_US)** to a certain task. A sustained attention to response task (SART) [(Silverstein & Palumbo, 1998)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074756329800017X) could be helpful to you ([here](http://www.marsja.se/sustained-attention-task-in-psychopy/) is a free PsychoPy script). SART seems to be a reliable measure for attention [(Smilek *et al*., 2010)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20452366).

Basically SART consists of a set of stimuli (*e.g.*, simple shapes) and the subject is asked to repeatedly give a response (*e.g.* a button press) when a certain event occurs (*e.g.* a shape changes color). Reductions in [correct rates](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3634902/), increased [lapse rates](http://davehunter.wp.st-andrews.ac.uk/2015/04/12/fitting-a-psychometric-function/), and/or decreased [reaction times](http://www.psych.upenn.edu/~saul/rt.experimentation.pdf) all may signal reduced attention to the task.

Admittedly I am not too familiar with these tests, but I do have a lot of experience with people loosing attention during tedious psychophysical tasks :) I hope the links and references provided here may be of further help.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Silverstein & Palumbo, Computers in Human Behavior (1998); **14**(3): 463-75](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074756329800017X)

**-** [Smilek *et al*., *Neuropsychologia* (2010); **48**(9): 2564-70](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20452366)</sub>

Comment: Thanks! So, is this only valid when used as the only task a user does, or could it also be done to track other tasks?

For example, suppose my subject is doing a given task on a computer (checking email vs. programming), and at random times these shapes take place on the screen and the user has to push a button if they are of equal shape. 

If the user performs better on these while programming than checking their email, can I say that he/she was more concentrated while programming?

Comment: @DanielNogueira97 - problem is that you can't really evaluate attention to task A when doing task B, because when you do it simultaneously a lapse on the attention task may be caused by a great focus on the programming task.

Comment: So the way, I suppose, is to come up with a way to create these "challenges"  within task A. Is that correct? Is there such challenges within computer tasks?